# Compare the dataframe value with the list of values and get the list of values which is not present in dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to compare the dataframe value with the list value and get the list of value which is not present in dataframe.

```
list =['682.9', '682.12', '682.11', '682.13', '682.14', '682.15']
```

Dataframe:

```
+-----------+
|sheetnumber|
+-----------+
|     682.11|
|     682.12|
|     682.13|
|     682.14|
|     682.15|
|      783.4|
+-----------+
```

Expected output:

```
['682.9']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the list into pyspark dataframe and do a left anti join with the other dataframe :

```
my_list = ['682.9', '682.12', '682.11', '682.13', '682.14', '682.15']
mylist_df = spark.createDataFrame([(n,) for n in my_list], ["sheetnumber"])

result = mylist_df.join(df, ["sheetnumber"], "left_anti")
output = [row.sheetnumber for row in result.collect()]

print(output)
#['682.9']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exceptAll` to compare the list (converted to a dataframe) with your dataframe:

```
mylist = ['682.9', '682.12', '682.11', '682.13', '682.14', '682.15']

diff = spark.createDataFrame([[i] for i in mylist]).exceptAll(df)

diff.show()
+-----+
|   _1|
+-----+
|682.9|
+-----+
```

And to get the results back as a list, you can do

```
result = [r[0] for r in diff.collect()]
# ['682.9']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter/where statement and check if it is in the list

```
my_list = ['682.9', '682.12', '682.11', '682.13', '682.14', '682.15']

df2=df.where(~df.sheetnumber.isin(my_list))
df2.show()

+-----------+
|sheetnumber|
+-----------+
|      783.4|
+-----------+

df3=df.filter(~df.sheetnumber.isin(my_list))
df3.show()

+-----------+
|sheetnumber|
+-----------+
|      783.4|
+-----------+
```

the `~` stands for not

Comment: this is not giving the required output of the question